# KendoUI grid cells trim the data values

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hi 
I'm experiencing some issues with the kendoui grid.

It looks like it is trimming the data value that is passed to the grid.
For example ***'chai               chai'***  will be trimmed to ***'chai chai'***.

This would be ok if only I didn't need to display the exact data that is in the database.

How to ignore this default behavior?

[Issues code sample](http://bit.ly/1aolw6H)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with the Kendo Grid. Its default HTML behavior to remove more than one space. To resolve this you just need to replace space with `&nbsp;` in your Product Name while creating  the products variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the CSS property to preserve white space here http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_text_white-space.asp